# bash script logic for looping through 24 items 6 at a time waiting for those tasks to complete then do the next 6 items until all 24 are completed

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
#Usage: runprocess.sh $1{duhname} $2{name-prefix} $3{'listsofitems'}
DUHNAME=$1
PREFIX=$2
SUFFIXES=$3

function wait_for_processes {
     DOINGSTUFF=$1
     #Check for running process:
     while [ $DOINGSTUFF -ne 0 ]
     do
            sleep 10
            #Check for running process
            bin/grep -i doingstuff | /usr/bin/cut -d '>' -f 2 | /usr/bin/cut -d '<' -f 1
            DOINGSTUFF=$1
            sleep 60
    done
}

function do_this_thing { #suffix
     SUFFIX=$1
     #Call a process to run against each item
     THE_NAME=$PREFIX$NUM
     /usr/bin/curl -v -X POST THE_NAME
}

#####        BEGIN MAIN SCRIPT      ############
wait_for_process 1
for NUM in $SUFFIXES
     do
             do_this_thing $NUM
             wait_for_process 1
     done
#####        END MAIN SCRIPT      ############
```

So have this working for do_this_thing 1 NUM at a time, but wanting to do 6 things at a time and then wait for them all to complete then do the next 6 NUM in the SUFFIX list.  Do I turn this into some array?

runprocess.sh $1{duhname} $2{name-prefix} $3{'listsofitems'}
duhname DUHONL
name-prefix TheMain
listsofitems "01 05 09 13 17 21 02 06 10 14 18 22 03 07 11 15 19 23 04 08 12 16 20 24"

I've lost my way.
Any link to similar example would be appreciated
Thoughts, thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to process 6 at a time then sync on completion?  If you just need to limit resource usage, then write a program to do 1 tas and run it with xargs -P6 -n1 ... (or with n tasks and run it with xargs -n6 ...).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to wait for all six to _complete_? Compared to running six tasks in parallel, and starting a new task whenever one finishes?

Comment: @AllanWind,  yes it seemed like it would be an easy way to limit resource usage

Comment: @dan,  waiting for all to complete (since they do not all finish at the same time)  easier then keeping track of starting a new process that already had one still running against any specific resource.   simple enough for what how i was thinking.

Comment: @HdCamper curl has `--parallel`

Comment: Just use **GNU Parallel** something like `parallel curl -v -X POST ::: thing1 thing2 otherthing`

Answer (score 1):

You clarified that the particular requirements are to limit resource usage. In which case I suggest that you modify your_program execute one task.  Then run it with with `xargs -n1 -P6 your_program`.  Here is a quick way to explore the behavior:

```
$ cat >my_program<<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo $@ start
sleep $(($RANDOM / 4000))
echo $@ end
EOF
$ chmod 755 my_program
$ seq 1 24 | xargs -n1 -P6 ./my_program
```